# Are the two cums related?

Tags: etymology, word-comparison, conjunction, preposition

In short, is there a relation between the preposition *cum* and the conjunction *cum*?

It makes some sense that the conjunction would come from the preposition.
One could interpret some *cum* clauses so that the main clause happens **with** a condition expressed in a subordinate clause or at the same time **with** the subordinate clause.
Perhaps some other kinds of connections would make sense, too.

I have seen both *cum*s discussed in many places, but I have never seen any comparison between them.
Is the similarity a coincidence or not?

Comment: I've read that the two senses of _cum_ converged from two unrelated Proto-Indo-European roots, the conjunction being a frozen accusative relative/interrogative pronoun and spelled _quom_ in Old Latin; its feminine sibling is _quam._ Hopefully this comment provides from useful search terms for someone who wants to dig deeper. [This](https://books.google.com/books?id=_q0AAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA203&dq=latin+cum+quom+proto-indo-european&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixiLjjqe7NAhXBOSYKHfO9AYQQuwUIQzAG#v=onepage&q=latin%20cum%20quom%20proto-indo-european&f=false) looks like a good start.

Comment: I'm wondering how many people came through HNQ not realising this is a question about latin.

Comment: @JanDvorak, I know the title is easy to misunderstand, but I chose it because it asks my question concisely. And if that HNQ listing brings more people to the site for whatever reason, I'm happy. The end justifies the means, I guess.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Indeed, what counts is a happy ending.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The similarity is a coincidence; these words are unrelated. Etymological dictionaries such as [De Vaan's](http://www.brill.com/etymological-dictionary-latin) give the following account of the two words:

The earlier form of the conjunction *cum* is *quom*; this is attested in early Latin, and also in the word *quoniam* (< *quom iam*). It is descended from Proto-Indo-European *kʷom "when" and has cognates in other IE languages, including English *when*.

The earlier form of the preposition *cum* is *com*, which remains its form in compounds (*com-*). This is from PIE *ḱom* "with", which also has reflexes in other languages, including the Germanic verbal prefix *ge-*.

The Italic cognates suffice to show that the first sound of the conjunction was a labiovelar (Umbrian **pumpe** "whenever", with *p* from *kʷ*) but the first sound of the preposition was a velar (Umbrian **kum-**).