# Understanding the sentence "Cum avis volat, alae moventur" from LLPSI

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

In Cap. X of LLPSI, Ørberg introduces these three sentences:

> Cum avis volat, alae moventur.
>
> Cum homo ambulat, pedes moventur.
>
> Cum piscis natat, cauda movetur.

While I understand the general meaning of each, the use of *cum* and passive verb make it a little more challenging for me.

I think that each more or less means something like:

> With wings the bird flies.
>
> With feet the person walks.
>
> With a tail the fish swims.

Is this correct, and is it just the placement of *cum* at the beginning of each sentence and use of comma that are making it more confusing for me? Shouldn't wings, feet, and tail be ablative?

Is he introducing *cum* as an adverb, so it would be *when a bird flies, the wings move*?

Comment: [Related question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1186/79) on *cum*.

Comment: Why would "cum" be an adverb, and not a conjunction?

Comment: I was basing that off of how [cum](http://archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/wordz.pl?keyword=cum) is listed in various Latin dictionaries, which give it as a preposition and adverb. This is an adverb that is functioning as a conjunction, right?

Comment: @FlatAssembler and Adam: As Cerberus points out in a comment under the answer, *cum* is a conjunction and a preposition. It does introduce adverbial clauses, but it is a conjunction. Listing it as an adverb strikes me as misleading, as it cannot really be used as one.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that! I was focused on the meaning and wasn't really thinking about what it was grammatically beyond that. It's helpful to know that it's actually a conjunction, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is indeed the conjunction *cum* "when" (from Old Latin *quom*), separate from the preposition *cum* "with" (from Old Latin *com*). <s>I'm not quite sure why the verbs are passive</s> EDIT: d_e in the comments has pointed out that moveō is generally transitive, so for a sort of "middle voice" meaning, the passive makes sense:

> When a bird flies, its wings move.

As you correctly surmised, the nouns would have to be ablative if it were the preposition "with". But *cum* is also specifically "with" in the sense of accompaniment ("I ate lunch with a friend"), not "with" in the sense of instrument ("I ate lunch with a fork"). So I wouldn't expect to see it used for feet, wings, etc: birds fly *using* their wings, not *alongside* their wings.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm guessing it's a sort of contrived way to show the passive of _moveo_.

Comment: If I would been asked to translate it I would rather use the active voice in English. ("The wings are moving"). because the verb *moveo* is transitive. using the collation *se movere* instead of the passive, sounds like the wings are an active agent. Kepler for example was using the passive *moventur* when he was saying the planets are moving.

Comment: @d_e Ah, I didn't know about that use of moveō (as used by Kepler)! A sort of middle-voice-esque usage?

Comment: @Draconis, I'm afraid I'm unqualified to answer this question. The usage of *moveo* simply caught me, as I was saying to myself *planetae se movent* (reluctantly using the active, but I then thought the passive is even worse), and then I saw the usage at Kepler. for example: *Nam sive Terra moveatur, sive Sol; demonstratum certe est, id corpus, quod movetur, moveri inaequabili ratione;*

Comment: @d_e Fair enough! I've edited my answer and might ask a new question about this later today.

Comment: It has been my experience that the passive and the active reflexive are generally used fairly interchangeably to render a middle sense, at least in classical Latin, apparently without a lot of concern over precisely how active an agent the subject really is in the action. You're just as likely to find se movent and moventur where the sense is clearly, as we would say in English, 'they move.' Perhaps some authors use the two constructions less discriminately but, as I said, this has been my experience. I think a new question about this is a great idea.

Comment: @cnread I agree that a new question about this would be great. For a related question, see https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9421/how-things-change-in-latin

Comment: @Mitomino, Ooh, thank you! I must have missed that question when you posted it. Maybe all that's really needed is renewed attention to, and an answer for, your old question (instead of a brand-new question), since you seem to have hit on the essential issue that has been raised here.

Comment: Just a minor qualification, Draconis. It's true that the verb _moveo_ is very often transitive. However, the strong statement that this verb "is always transitive" is not correct, as shown by the following examples from Livy: _Romae per idem tempus duo maximi fuerunt terrores, diutinus alter sed segnior: **terra** dies duodequadraginta **mouit**_ (Liv. 35.40.7). See the very same intransitive use of _terra mouit_ in Liv. 40.59.7. See also my answer to a previous question of yours on this topic: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7166/did-latin-have-any-ergative-verbs/9378#9378

Comment: @Mitomino Changed to "generally"; I'd forgotten about that old question